# Передача по bluetooth без uuid

Tags: android, bluetooth

Чтобы подключиться к девайсу, используется код

```
BluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                        MY_UUID)
```

Соответственно, чтобы прослушивать ожидание на подключение, используется

```
BluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME,
                        MY_UUID)
```

**Вопрос**: как передать файл на девайс, не зная uuid? Как в таком случае работают стандартные программы передачи файлов на различных устройствах различных производителей?

Comment: вы видели вот этот ответ?  
 http://stackoverflow.com/a/13977356/1654690

Comment: @Andreich т.е. в стандартных приложениях используются некие общие сервис-uuid?

Comment: похоже на то

Comment: @gcoder, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.